# How to hide top links from customer groups

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, toplinks

Is it possible to hide certain top links depending on the customer group?
As we have anew feature which we have added a link to in the top link but it is only available to certain customers.

We have declared the link an xml file, and shows up perfectly i just now need to know if it is possible to hide the link if a customer is not logged in or is logged in but is not in a certain group

```
<reference name="top.links">
                <block type="advancedquickorder/index" name="add.advancedquickorder.link">
                    <action method="addAdvancedquickorderLink" ifconfig="advancedquickorder/general/active"><param>top</param></action>              
                </block>
            </reference>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the below codes,
In config.xml

```
   <frontend>     
      <events>
        <controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before>
           <observers>
              <Mymodule>
                 <class>Namespace_Mymodule_Model_Observer</class>
                 <method>addmyblock</method>
              </Mymodule>
           </observers>
         </controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before>
       </events>
    </frontend>
```

In observer.php

```
class Namespace_Mymodule_Model_Observer
{

    public function addmyblock(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){

        $loggedIn = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();
        // add Handler when customer is loggedin
        if($loggedIn){
            $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(); 
            $groupname = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId)->getCustomerGroupCode();
            if($groupname == "group name"){
                $layout = $observer->getLayout();
                $layout->getUpdate()->addUpdate('<reference name="top.links">
                                <remove name="add.advancedquickorder.link"/></reference>');              
                $layout->generateXml(); 
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

You can remove any of the top links with the above code

Comment: I took the group name bit out and just done the IF statement from the groupID

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by create handler according  to Customer group using magento/event observer.

On `controller_action_layout_load_before` event fire an observer  which `will insert a new handler on current layout`.

This layout name should  be  `dynamic basic of Customer group name`.

If a `general group` customer is loggin then it handler  anme is  `customer_group_general`

Logic like  `customer_group_CustomerGROUPCODE`.

**Config.xml code is :**
`

```
       <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_layout_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <customer_group_wise_handler>
                        <class>stackexchange70064/observer</class>
                        <method>addCustomerLoadLayout</method>
                    </customer_group_wise_handler>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_load_before>
       </events>
 </frontend>
```

`

**Observer code:**

```
<?php
class Magento_Stackexchange70064_Model_Observer{

    public function addCustomerLoadLayout($observer)
    {
        $loggedIn = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();
        // add Handler when customer is loggedin
        if($loggedIn):

        $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
        //Get customer Group name

        $group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId);

        // add handler to current layout
        $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate()
        ->addHandle('customer_group_'.strtolower($group->getData('customer_group_code')));
        //Mage::log('customer_group_'.strtolower($group->getData('customer_group_code')), null, 'logfile.log');
        endif;

    }
}
```

You can full modules at [Github](https://github.com/devamitbera/magento-stackexchange/tree/master/70064/app)

Then those handler and using layout  tag remove   attribute remove the a toplink for a particular customer grop

For example:

suppose  want to remove `add.advancedquickorder.link` block for `general Customer group.`

**Then try this**

```
<customer_group_general>
   <reference name="top.links"><remove name="add.advancedquickorder.link"/></reference>
</customer_group_gerenal>
```

Comment: I implemented your solution but it didnt seem to work, i just wanted to check with you that i was implementing it correct. I created a directory in app/code/local/CGroup/CGroup/etc and Model and added your config code to the app/code/local/CGroup/CGroup/etc and added the observe code to the app/code/local/CGroup/CGroup/Model but changing the class to class CGroup_CGroup_Model_Observer. Is that correct or am i mssing something?

Comment: There are issue xml , i have update code

Comment: I used all the files from Github but it still doesnt work