# Add link to customer account navigation based on Customer Group

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, link

I'd like to add a link to 'customer_account_navigation' block, but add it only to customers who belong to Wholesale customer group. Is that possible? Any suggestions?

local.xml:

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="profileimage">
            <name>set_profileimage</name>
            <path>profileimage/customer/form</path>
            <label>My Profileimage</label>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide top links from customer groups](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/70064/how-to-hide-top-links-from-customer-groups)

Comment: This is the half part of the answer but your link helped me a lot. Should I post the answer or accept duplicate?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Not even the same block @Klettseb

Comment: @ktsixit self-answer is preferable. May be 24-48 hours before you can accept.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the problem

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="profileimage">
            <name>set_profileimage</name>
            <path>profileimage/customer/form</path>
            <label helper="profileimage/getCustomerMenuName"/>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

And add below function to helper "Data.php" of the module

```
 public function getCustomerMenuName()
    {
        if(customer group check logic) {
            return "My Profileimage";
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: This will not work it will display blank space in account navigation